# Text isn't aligning with an object correctly in html

Tags: html, text-alignment

So I'm trying to make a form with a message box, but it won't align correctly; it keeps pushing the text to the bottom of the area it takes up..
I've accepted putting in a break between the text field and the message field for a long time, but there's a break, so it isn't aligned there either...

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2U2PJ/

```
    <form action="sending.php" method="post" name="Contact Form" id="form1" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('Name','','R','E-mail','','R','Device','','R','Message','','R')return document.MM_returnValue" encytype="text/plain">
                            <p>
                                <label><font size="3">Name: </font>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="25" /><font size="2"> <font color="red"><span id="req_3" class="req">*</span></font></font></label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label><font size="3">Email:</font>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="E-mail" type="text" id="E-mail" size="25" /> <font size="2"><font color="red"><span id="req_3" class="req">*</span></font></font></label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label><font size="3">Review:</font>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea name="Message" cols="35" rows="7" id="Message" placeholder="Y U SO BROKE MR. THINGY D;"></textarea>
                            </p>
                                </label>
                            <label>
                                <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
                            </label>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Could you please post your `CSS`? Or perhaps a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com). Or is everything inline?

Comment: I added a jsfiddle. Forgot about that little feature :p

Comment: Tip: You should use CSS with your html.

Comment: Not trying to be snarky, but I would, if someone showed me what to do with it.
But this problem has occurred since I first used this form several years ago, and I had no css page then (I know, I know....but I was new to this then).

Comment: Let me make an expanded fiddle for you... One moment.

Comment: "I was new to this then" ok so I don't mean to sound mean with this but someone has to bring you to this decade.  That HTML is valid and will render, but almost all of it is either unnecessary or could be managed better with numbers and CSS.  `<font>` went away with HTML 5, was deprecated in HTML 4.01 and previous to that we had to use a `<table height="100%">` to force our text to the top of a column.  `&nbsp;` brings me back to middle school.  And makes me want to cringe.  It's like when someone uses a bunch of spaces in a word doc instead of hitting tab once or twice.

Comment: Added totally revised version with MUCH less markup, and using CSS @Chris

Comment: much less markup != better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment. Use CSS. This should get you on the correct path:

http://jsfiddle.net/2U2PJ/3/

css:

```
.contact-form .field label { width: 100px; display:inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
.contact-form .req { color: red; }
.contact-form .field .textbox { width: 180px; }
```

html:

```
<div class="contact-form">
<form action="sending.php" method="post" name="Contact Form" id="form1" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('Name','','R','Email','','R','Device','','R','Message','','R')return document.MM_returnValue" encytype="text/plain">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="Name">Name:</label>
        <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" class="textbox" />
        <span id="req_3" class="req">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="Email">Email:</label>
        <input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" class="textbox" />
        <span id="req_3" class="req">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="Message">Review:</label>
        <textarea name="Message" cols="35" rows="7" id="Message" placeholder="Y U SO BROKE MR. THINGY D;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: THAT IS BEAUTIFUL, thank you!! Could you maybe take a look at this page (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp) and implement that? I sort of had it working beforehand, but I'm not sure how to do it with your code..

Comment: In your 'onsubmit', change `E-mail` to `Email`

Answer (score 0):

#### Full Code to simplify your issue!

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/jLXsV/2/

**HTML:**

```
<form action="sending.php" method="post" name="Contact Form" id="form1" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('Name','','R','E-mail','','R','Device','','R','Message','','R')return document.MM_returnValue" encytype="text/plain">
    <p>
    <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Review:</label>
        <textarea rows="7" cols="35"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
```

**CSS:**

```
input, textarea {
    width:200px;
    margin-left:15px;
}
label {
    float:left;
    min-width:100px;
}
```

#### With your IDs

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/jLXsV/3/

Comment: You will have to add in `id`s and such, but avoid `inline styling` as much as possible, as if you ever have to change anything it's a PAIN to update...

Comment: If you feel this answer is acceptable, please select the `green checkbox` by the voting arrows.

Comment: Sorry nicholas, but I needed a lot of the markups that were included, and jzm's had everything I needed.
Thank you so very much for your help though!!

Comment: This doesn't help....? [Your Code With Markup](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/jLXsV/3/)